# Aggregating with multiple functions with axis=1

Tags: python, pandas

What is the best way to aggregate a data frame across columns (axis=1) applying multiple functions?

Applying a list of functions works as expected with the default axis=0:

```
In [7]: tsdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'],
                            index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=2))
   ...: tsdf

Out[7]:
                   A         B         C
2000-01-01 -0.496619  0.282351  0.222707
2000-01-02  1.185002 -0.988669 -2.300515

In [8]: tsdf.agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'])
Out[8]:
             A         B         C
min  -0.496619 -0.988669 -2.300515
max   1.185002  0.282351  0.222707
mean  0.344191 -0.353159 -1.038904
```

But fails when using axis=1:

```
In [9]: tsdf.agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'], axis=1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-ad4197b17943> in <module>()
----> 1 tsdf.agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'], axis=1)

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in aggregate(self, func, axis, *args, **kwargs)
   4152                 pass
   4153         if result is None:
-> 4154             return self.apply(func, axis=axis, args=args, **kwargs)
   4155         return result
   4156

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   4260                         f, axis,
   4261                         reduce=reduce,
-> 4262                         ignore_failures=ignore_failures)
   4263             else:
   4264                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   4356             try:
   4357                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
-> 4358                     results[i] = func(v)
   4359                     keys.append(v.name)
   4360             except Exception as e:

TypeError: ("'list' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 2000-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Is there anything I am missing? I thought (naively) that the axes were treated more or less symmetrically. What is the best way to apply multiple aggregation functions with axis=1?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I think this is a bug listed at this link: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16679

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug listed on [Pandas-Dev GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16679):

However, there is a workaround:

```
tsdf.T.agg(['min','max','mean']).T
```

Output:

```
                 min       max      mean
2000-01-01  0.187605  1.707985  0.874033
2000-01-02 -1.156725  1.121996 -0.009986
```

Comment: Thank you, Scott. Good to know the bug has been reported. I came up with the same workaround yesterday. Best regards.